# batch append contents from txt to another txt

Tags: batch-file

Hello apologies if this seems too easy

I have a text1.txt that has the following text:

```
Give it a break John {
   Give 123sawnghaksdsj your best shot
},

Give it a break Mike {
   Give asdwsadasdsad23 your lack shit
},
```

And from text2.txt

```
Main mac(){
    Jheader.pin.all
}
```

I would like to append content of text2.txt
to text1.txt
after

```
 Give it a break Mike {
       Give asdwsadasdsad23 your lack shit
    },
```

Without erasing anything in text1.txt

> The text above are just examples close to my scenario.

I've tried searching google, but all I get is echo to a text file which will either erase the contents or append to last line :(

They were useful but not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question solved!

I found this and is exactly what I wanted:
[Batch: insert lines from a .txt file into a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485139/batch-insert-lines-from-a-txt-file-into-a-txt-file)